# comparing two table only the max id to be consider on the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table 1 
id          rollnumber       Name 
1                 4               John Doe

table 2 
id       rollnumber    Name 
1            4                  Jane Doe 
2            4                  John Doe

Here's my query statement..

```
select * from table1
inner join table2
on table2.rollnumber = table1.rollnumber
where table1.Name <> table2.Name
```

My objective here is to compare table1 to table2's highest ID with reference to rollnumber and in this case the result with this query should be none... Your help is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from table1 t1
cross apply ( select * from (select top 1 * from table2 t2 where t1.rn = t2.rn order by t2.id desc) t where t.name <> t1.name) c
```

Comment: Hi I have a question is this applicable in insert select subquery?

Comment: -Thanks for the suggestion...gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (ID INT, RollNumber INT, Name VARCHAR(100))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (ID INT, RollNumber INT, Name VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(1,4,'John Doe')

INSERT INTO @table2 
VALUES  (1,4,'Jane Doe'),
        (2,4,'John Doe');

SELECT  A.RollNumber,
        A.ID,
        A.Name,
        C.max_id
FROM @table1 A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @table2 B WHERE A.RollNumber = B.RollNumber) C(max_id)
WHERE A.ID = C.max_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table1 a
join (select max(Id) id, rollnumber,max(name) name from table2 
group by rollnumber) t on t.id = a.id and t.rollnumber = a.rollnumber and t.name <> a.name;
```

> This is a generic solution which will work in popular databases. Also
>   at times better than apply functions in performance.

Comment: Actually fot such tasks where join condition is hard to develop apply will be faster. But it depends. And you can not just say that join is times faster then apply.

Comment: yes.. it depends. That's why I deliberately said at times.

Comment: Thanks for formatting. I couldn't find the symbol on my phone.

Comment: @JoseTuttu -Thanks for the suggestion...gladly appreciated